# Should babel-polyfill@7 be imported in index.js or in webpack entry point?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

In Babel7, `babel-preset-env` has the new options [`useBuiltIns: usage` and `useBuiltIns: entry`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html#usebuiltins) to only import individual polyfills from `babel-polyfill` when they are used/based on environment.

I used to simply add `babel-polyfill` to the webpack entry-point: `entry: ['@babel/polyfill', 'index.js']`. Is this not the recommended way to do this anymore - because webpack would include the whole `babel-polyfill` and not the individual core-js ones?